# Prove that Acyclic Subgraph is NP-Hard by showing Independent Set can be reduced to Acyclic Subgraph

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, reductions, np-hard

I am trying to prove that the Acyclic Subgraph Problem (AS) is NP-hard by showing that the Independent Set Problem (IS) is polynomially reducible to AS.

**AS is as follows:** Given a directed graph G = (V, E) and an integer k, does G contain a subset V' of
k vertices such that the induced subgraph on V'is acyclic?

**IS is as follows:** Given an undirected graph G = (V, E) and an integer k, does G contain a subset V' of k vertices such that no two vertices in V'are adjacent to one another?

**I have developed the following:**
Given an undirected graph, *G = (V,E)*, we can construct a directed graph, *D =(V, E')*. We do this by addd the edges *(u,v)* and *(v,u)* for every edge in *E*. If *G* has an independent set of size *k*, then the corresponding vertices in *D* are an acyclic subgraph. Similarly, if *D* has an acyclic subgraph of size *k*, then those *k* vertices must form an independent set in *D* as if there is an edge between two vertices in *D*. Then, there is a directed cycle between them, thus those *k* vertices form an independent set in *G*.

Can anyone help me further with this proof? I am not sure if what I have is going in the right direction or not.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Very good improvement of your question :) I also think your proof is perfectly valid. In a graph where every arc has a reverse arc, two adjacent nodes can never be part of a set that induces an acyclic graph

Comment: your proof is correct, no need to go further...